# List iteration with substitution into one-liner

Tags: python, list, for-loop, one-liner

I want to turn the following `for` loop:

```
n = 10
x0 = 0
values = [x0]
for i in range(n):
    x0 = f(x0)
    values.append(x0)
```

into a one liner. I figured I could do something like this:

```
values = [f(x0) for i in range(n)]
```

but I need to update the value of `x0` in each instance of the loop. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Walrus operator](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.8.html#assignment-expressions) `:=` to the rescue:

```
>>> x0 = 0
>>> def f(x): return x*2 + 1
... 
>>> [x0:=f(x0) for _ in range(10)]
[1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127, 255, 511, 1023]
>>> x0
1023 # x0 was modified
```

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that existed. Thanks, just what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

In addition to walrus, `more_itertools` has a function `iterate` that does this repeated application:

```
import more_itertools as mo

mo.take(10, mo.iterate(f, x0))
```